# Deploy app to Azure from Monodevelop on Mac OS X?

Tags: azure, mono

Is there a decent way to deploy apps to Windows Azure from Monodevelop running on Mac OS X?

EDIT: I'm curious if it's possible to "Web Deploy" from Mono on a Mac to Azure using the Azure Accelerator For Web Roles (http://blog.ntotten.com/2011/07/05/windows-azure-accelerator-for-web-roles/).

Answer (score 0):

Can't make the Azure package (.cspkg file) on MAX OS X.  You should make a package by the Azure SDK on Windows as of now. You need to create a package on other Windows PC or VirtualBox/VMWare virtual machine.

Comment: Okay, so if I create the Azure package on a Windows machine, how do I create a relationship between that package and the project I create in Monodevelop?  Right now, I'm using Visual Studio with an Azure Deployment Project, so I'm a little confused on how the .cspkg file works.

Comment: Developer could make deploy package using the CSPack commandline tool in Azure SDK.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432988.aspx